# A word meaning or having to do with "love of fighting"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What nouns are there meaning "***love of fighting***", or "***excitement caused by getting into fights***". Adjectives would also be useful.

Example sentences:

> His ...... (love of fighting) will be the death of him.
>
> His ....... (fight-loving) wife will take that as justification to smack him round the head.

Comment: I'm afraid we need a little more to go on (otherwise we'll come up with answers, you'll veto them for reasons we did not know about, and the cycle will repeat ad nauseam). Have you found and rejected some words already? What do you need this word for? What part of speech should it be? (Noun, I'm guessing, but it's best to be explicit.) Etc., etc.

Comment: Possibly "pugilist". Not an exact match but can't think of a closer one.

Comment: a "brawler" (or a scrapper) ?

Comment: I would say "bellicose" (and all it's synonyms).

Comment: Bullies love fighting.

Comment: I was going to offer "feisty," but after looking it up, it seems I've been using it wrong all these years.  My family uses it for pets that are playing aggressively (i.e. mock fighting).  It does, however, mean spirited or animated, which is close.

Comment: @wariya Quite the contrary, I think.

Comment: [Belloc](http://www.mainlesson.com/display.php?author=belloc&book=more&story=porcupine&PHPSESSID=9f5cea60775fade7f2886ea4f7e3fd7d) offers a nonce coinage: What? Would you slap the Porcupine? / Unhappy child--desist! / Alas that any friend of mine / Should turn tupto-philist!

Comment: @BrianDonovan actually, yeah you're right. Bullies are cowards.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I think the adjective form you were looking for is "pugnacious". A pugalist is one who fights; someone is pugnacious if they tend to start fights.

Comment: Fighting for sport? Out of anger? Some specificity would be good.

Comment: @keshlam agreed.

Comment: @LiamJoyce - I've put some example sentences in. If they're not appropriate please change them to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

***Aggressive***, ***combative***, ***pugnacious***, or ***belligerent*** can mean one who enjoys fighting.
[**Aggressive:**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aggressive?s=t)

> characterized by or tending toward unprovoked offensives, attacks, invasions, or the like; militantly forward or menacing

[**Combative**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/combative?s=t)

> ready or inclined to fight; pugnacious

[**Pugnacious**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pugnacious?s=t)

> inclined to quarrel or fight readily; quarrelsome; belligerent; combative.

[**Belligerent**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/belligerent?s=t)

> of warlike character; aggressively hostile; bellicose

Definitions from Dictionary.com

I would use these to describe a lover of fighting.

Answer (score 8):

Consider **bellicose** (or belligerent).

> Definition: inclined or eager to fight; aggressively hostile;
>   belligerent; pugnacious; of warlike character; aggressively hostile.
>
> Example: *She is the right person to deal with angry, belligerent
>   clients*.

Comment: Synonyms: belligerent, aggressive, hostile, warlike, warmongering, hawkish, antagonistic, pugnacious, truculent, confrontational, contentious, militant, combative.

Comment: Please cite the source of your definition.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on context, consider:

***bloodlust***

> bloodlust (also, blood thirstiness)
>
> 1. A desire for extreme violence and carnage, often aroused in the heat of battle and leading to uncontrolled slaughter and torture.
> 2. The desire for bloodshed. [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bloodlust)

***quarrelsomeness***

> quarrelsome: having or showing an eagerness to fight [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quarrelsome)